# Law of large numbers with convergence in mean

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, lp-spaces

I have very little experience with probability and I would like some help in the following exercise: suppose $(X_n)$ is a sequence of identically distributed independent real-valued random variables, with $E|X_i|<\infty$. Because they are independently distributed, it follows that $EX_n = EX_1$ for all $n$ (I thought that this would be true because they are identically distributed, however I don't know how to prove it).

I must show that the sequence $\overline{X}_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ converges in $L^1$ to $EX_1$. Can someone give me any hints or references on how to do this?

Comment: $X_n$ are identically distributed means that all random variables are defined on the same probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$. Since $\mathbb EX_n = \int X_n\,\mathrm dP$, we have that $\mathbb E X_n$ is the same for all $n$. For your question: if $\mathbb EX_n^2<\infty$ the L1 convergence is easy to prove. I am not sure whether L1 convergence even holds in the given case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Weak Law of Large Numbers, you know that $\bar X_n$ converges to $EX_1$ in probability. If you manage to prove that the sequence $\bar X_n$ is uniformly integrable, [you can thus conclude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability#Relation_to_convergence_of_random_variables) that it converges in $L^1$ as well.

To prove the uniform integrability of the sample mean $\bar X_n$, first prove that the sequence $X_n$ is uniformly integrable. Then, mainly using triangle inequality, you should be able to prove that $\bar X_n$ is also uniformly integrable and get your desired result.

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to prove that the sequence is uniformly integrable?

Comment: Using the $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}E(|X_n|\mathbf1_{|X_n|>k}) = 0$ definition of uniform integrability, one way to do it would be to first prove that the (single element) family $\{X_1\} $ is u.i. (apply dominated convergence theorem on $|X_1|\mathbf1_{|X_1|>k} $, letting $k \to \infty$) and then conclude for the whole sequence $X_n$ by using the fact that all the $X_i$ follow the same distribution.